# Invalid Elif Syntax Error in Python 3 program

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting an invalid sytnax error in the elif statement of my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
# define the functions for each math operation
#
def add (a, b) :

    return a + b

def subtract (a, b) :

    return a - b

def multiply (a, b) :

    return a * b

def divide (a, b) :

    return a / b

def remainder (a, b) :

    return a % b

def welcome_message ( first_name ) :
    print ("Hi ", first_name, " " ". Welcome to Project 3!")

welcome_message("Prof. Shah")

loop = 1

while loop ==1:
    print ("Select operation.")
    print ("1. Add")
    print ("2. Subtract")
    print ("3. Multiply")
    print ("4. Divide")
    print ("5. Remainder")
    choice = input("Enter choice :")
    num1 = int(input |"Please enter your first number: ")
    num2 = int(input |"Please enter your second number: ")

    if choice == '1' :
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '2' :
                print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '3' : 
                print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '4' :
                print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '5' :
                print(num1, "%", num2, "=", remainder (num1,num2)
```

Comment: You know you can [`from operator import add, sub, div, mul, mod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), right?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm still a work in progress! LOL

Answer (score 2):

```
if choice == '1' :
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))
elif choice == '2' :
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1,num2))
...
```

your indentation seems to be off, and you were missing a closing brace at the end of every print statement.

Comment: Got it! Thanks Haleemur. Now I'm getting the following error when I try to run the program: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cherylragin/Desktop/Intro to Interactive Design/Week 4 Assignments/Project3_copy_3_yes.py", line 38, in <module>
    num1 = int(input |"Please enter your first number: ")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Comment: the problem is in these two lines: `num1 = int(input |"Please enter your first number: ")` and `num2 = int(input |"Please enter your second number: ")`. Try to solve it yourself, it should not be too too hard, and if you can't, please post on SO with what you tried. Good luck!

Comment: Yes...I figured it out: I entered the | symbol in error. When I made the corrections, the program ran, but I couldn't get it to calculate.

Comment: you're almost there. hint: count the opening and closing brackets and make sure they match :)

Comment: I changed it to this: num1 = int(input ("Please enter your first number: "))
 num2 = int(input ("Please enter your second number: ")) I'm having a hard time trying to figure out where I went wrong with outputting the answer.

Comment: great! If you've found this answer useful, and it satisfies your original question, please accept it to inform others that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
if choice == '1' :
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '2' :
                print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '3' : 
                print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '4' :
                print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide (num1,num2)
        elif choice == '5' :
                print(num1, "%", num2, "=", remainder (num1,num2)
```

Problem is in here. if "if" block is going to process, then you have to start with if after then elif. like:

```
if choice == '1' :
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add (num1,num2)
elif choice == '2' :
                print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract (num1,num2)
elif choice == '3' : 
                print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply (num1,num2)
elif choice == '4' :
                print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide (num1,num2)
elif choice == '5' :
                print(num1, "%", num2, "=", remainder (num1,num2)
```