# Unable to calculate Python 3 program

Tags: python

I am unable to get my Python 3 created program to stop running my loop. What am I doing wrong? I need to be able to return to the main menu after outputting each function.

Help!

```
  # define functions
  def add(x, y):
       """This function adds two numbers"""

      return x + y

  def subtract(x, y):
      """This function subtracts two numbers"""

      return x - y

  def multiply(x, y):
      """This function multiplies two numbers"""

      return x * y

  def divide(x, y):
      """This function divides two numbers"""

      return x / y

  # take input from the user
  loop = 1

  while loop ==1:
      print ("Hi Prof. Shah! Welcome to my Project 3 calculator!")
      print("Please select an operation.")
      print("1.Add")
      print("2.Subtract")
      print("3.Multiply")
      print("4.Divide")
      print("5.Remainder")
      print("6.Exit")

      choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4/5/6):")

      num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
      num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

      if choice == '1':
      print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

      elif choice == '2':
      print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

      elif choice == '3':
      print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

      elif choice == '4':
      print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

      elif choice == '5':
      print(num1,"%",num2,"=", remainder(num1,num2))

      elif choice == '6':       
      print("Goodbye, Prof. Shah!")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please properly indent your code, otherwise we have no way of telling what it actually does because it's Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid Elif Syntax Error in Python 3 program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347442/invalid-elif-syntax-error-in-python-3-program)

Comment: I tried cutting and pasting my code directly from Python 3, but I kept getting an error message on Stackoverflow. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever setting the value of `loop` with the expression `loop = 1`. At some point later on, you need to change it to a value other than 1 in order to exit the loop, since the condition is `loop == 1`.

Set the value of `loop` to something other than 1 at the appropriate point in the loop.

Comment: This is the right diagnosis of the problem. Note that a more Pythonic approach to loops like this is often to make the loop deliberately infinite, using `while True`, then later, exit the loop with `break`. Some programmers don't like this style though (they don't like `break` because it's a form of `goto`), so use it with caution.

Comment: Correct. My Prof. doesn't want us using breaks for this project.

Comment: I tried adding this but I kept receiving indentation errors. : elif choice == '6' :
            loop = 0
print("Good-bye, Prof. Shah!")

Comment: The two lines below `elif choice == '6'` have to be indented one level more (i.e. four spaces more) than the `elif choice == '6'` line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "break" after each "print", so that the while loop can break after printing the information. For example:

```
if choice == '1':
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))
    break
elif choice == '2':
    print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))
    break
```

Comment: Will this return me to my main menu after each print?

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the value of `loop`, it is causing the infinite loop.

Here is a suggestion:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    print ("Hi Prof. Shah! Welcome to my Project 3 calculator!")
    print("Please select an operation.")
    print("1.Add")
    print("2.Subtract")
    print("3.Multiply")
    print("4.Divide")
    print("5.Remainder")
    print("6.Exit")
    choice = int(input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4/5/6):")) #dangeeer!!
    if choice >= 1 and choice < 6: #here you keep inside the loop.
        x = float(input("First value:")) #dangeeer!!
        y = float(input("Second value:")) #dangeeer!!
        if choice == 1 : print(add(x, y))
        elif choice == 2: print(subtract(x, y))
        elif choice == 3: print(multiply(x, y))
        elif choice == 4: print(divide(x, y))
        elif choice == 5: print(remainder(x, y))
    elif choice == 6: #here you get out of the loop
        print("Goodbye, Prof. Shah!")
        flag = False
    else:
        print("Choose a number between 1 and 6")
```

Comment: I received an invalid syntax message when I added the following code after your suggestion: elif == 6: print(Goodbye, Prof. Shah!)

Comment: put `elif choice == 6 : flag = False`

Comment: Correction...I added this: 
    else: flag = False
elif choice == 6: print(Goodbye, Prof. Shah!)

Comment: remove `else: flag = False` and put `elif choice == 6 : flag = False` in the same place.

Comment: Do I add that directly under the previous code? What about my print stateent? print(Goodbye, Prof. Shah!)

Comment: A put a extra else there for choice values that aren't between 1 and 6.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help on this! You rock! I want to add "Your answer is " before the answer is displayed, but I'm doing something wrong. This is what I added: print("Your answer is :" "subtract(x, y)")

Comment: convert the result to string and concatenate: `print("Your answer is: " + str(subtract(x, y)))`

Comment: Yep..that did the trick! Thanks again! I'm new to Python and was getting very frustrated on something so simple! LOL

Comment: It's ok... just give time to the time :D